# Trigger a Job on BOOT_COMPLETE in API > 26

Tags: android, background-process, android-intentservice, bootcompleted

I'm in the process of creating an app which displays a notification whenever a message (received via MQTT) arrives. I'd like this to happen regardless of whether the app is running or not.

I've done a bit of research and found that I can register a receiver in my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="anonymised">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService" />

        <service
            android:name="anonymised.systemservice.MqttNotificationService"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
            android:label="LabelForConnection"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

        <service
            android:name="anonymised.systemservice.NotificationJob"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
            android:label="LabelForJob"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

        <receiver
            android:name="anonymised.StartServiceReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I've seen a few articles which have mentioned that implicit receivers are being blocked, however BOOT_COMPLETED was one of the ones to continue being supported post API 26.

My gradle file contains:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
}
```

My code is based on: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html
Which seems to indicate that:

```
package anonymised.systemservice;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class StartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "MQTT_RECI";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ServiceReceiver started");
        SchedulerUtils.scheduleJob(context);
    }
}
```

Should then trigger the `onReceive` method, when

```
~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ ./adb root
~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ ./adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

is run. However, when I run the ADB commands I get nothing in my application logs (relating to the issue) and the following in the system_process logs:

```
2019-12-23 15:30:33.958 1826-1851/system_process W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED flg=0x400010 } to anonymised/.systemservice.StartServiceReceiver
```

As a final test, I triggered `SchedulerUtils.scheduleJob(getApplicationContext());` from my activity and closed the app. Which worked, until the job was rescheduled and I received:

```
2019-12-23 15:35:13.089 5700-5700/uk.ac.mmu.dominicsutherland.hotellock E/MAIN_REPOSITORY: MQTT Connection failed
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=anonymised/org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{9f137b0 u0a67 TRNB idle change:uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1577)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1532)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:664)
        at org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient.connect(MqttAndroidClient.java:414)
        at anonymised.MainRepository.<init>(MainRepository.java:60)
        at anonymised.systemservice.NotificationJob.onStartJob(NotificationJob.java:30)
        at android.app.job.JobService$1.onStartJob(JobService.java:62)
        at android.app.job.JobServiceEngine$JobHandler.handleMessage(JobServiceEngine.java:108)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I've had a look at: [Background execution not allowed receiving intent BOOT_COMPLETED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50040617/background-execution-not-allowed-receiving-intent-boot-completed) however I'd prefer to stick with the method using the AndroidManifest and my receiver if possible.

Comment: Have you found a solution?  I am wondering the same.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I ended up creating a foreground process to receive the MQTT messages